# Worked before, but Run time error 91 now

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

Last week I ran my Excel vba code without errors multiple times but now am getting run-time error '91 object variable or with block variable not set.  In the below code, it's stopping at `LastRow=SummarySheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange.Count`

From research, I believe the error is telling me **SummarySheet** was never set, but you can see in the code it is.  I'm new to vba, how can I code it so it works again?

Update:   I have tried `ActiveWorkbook` `ThisWorkbook` and `Workbooks("Summary")` all to no avail.  Further research on the error is leading to believe me I am not creating a valid object reference. I have confirmed the Worksheet name matches between the actual Workbook and code. From the answers so far and other sample code I've investigated, I think I'm on the right coarse. I feel like I'm missing something simple because I'm a newbie.

Update2: I have it figured out.  My mistake was actually in the `LastRow = SummarySheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange.Count` line.  The 3 should be a 1.  Third column on the page, but first column in the table. Thank you for the help, it gave me the clue I needed to solve my issue.

```
Sub MergeSelectedPowerSpec()
        Dim SummarySheet As Worksheet
        Dim FolderPath As String
        Dim SelectedFiles() As Variant
        Dim NRow As Long
        Dim FileName As String
        Dim NFile As Long
        Dim WorkBk As Workbook
        Dim SourceRange As Range
        Dim DestRange As Range
        Dim Tbl As ListObject
        Dim LastRow As Long
        Dim UnitNum As String
        Dim RightPos As Long
        Dim LeftPos As Long
        Dim Odo As Long


' Sets Data Entry sheet as the location the merged data will go.
Set SummarySheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Entry")


' Modify this folder path to point to the files you want to use.
FolderPath = "C:\Users\jziqsb\Desktop\FE Spreadsheet\"

' Set the current directory to the the folder path.
ChDrive FolderPath
ChDir FolderPath

' Open the file dialog box and filter on Excel files, allowing multiple files
' to be selected.
SelectedFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
    filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*", MultiSelect:=True)

' LastRow gets the number of rows in the table with data.
LastRow = SummarySheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange.Count

' NRow keeps track of where to insert new rows in the destination workbook.
NRow = LastRow + 3
```

Comment: Seems like someone renamed your table.

Comment: I checked the table name and it is still Table1.  I opened another, similar workbook and the code works there so I now know the code works.  I need to figure out the issue with the original workbook.  Thank you, Jeeped, for taking a look.

Comment: Silly question, you're **positive** the `Data Entry` sheet is being set correctly? If you also do `SummarySheet.Cells(1,1).Value = "Test"`, does `A1` in that sheet have "Test"?  *Maybe* try `Set SummarySheet = ThisWorkbook...` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`?

Comment: @BruceWayne I just tried the test you suggested and changing to `ThisWorkbook` I now get Run Time error 9. Hovering over the `Set SummarySheet = ThisWorkbook...` while stepping through it says `SummarySheet = Nothing`.

Comment: @J.Nord `Set SummarySheet = ThisWorkbook`? This is expecting a `Worksheet` - so maybe change that to `Set SummarySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Entry")`.

Comment: @J.Nord I'd suggest fully declaring your variables - instead of `ThisWorkbook`, use `Workbooks("MyWorkbookName").Worksheets("MyWorksheetName")`, etc.

Comment: @BruceWayne You should clarify your `Set SummarySheet = ThisWorkbook...` comment, as it looks like he actually tried it with the ellipsis. Looks like he's new to VBA.

Comment: @J.Nord - To clarify, try `Set SummarySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Entry")`

Comment: @BruceWayne That is what I did, but still returns `SummarySheet = Nothing`.  I feel like I'm missing something very basic about object references.  This macro is currently saved in my personal.xlsb worrkbook which didn't seem to cause issues Friday, but could that be part of the issue?

Comment: Ah!  When you use `ActiveWorkbook`, it's going to (obviously) use whatever workbook is the active one.  `ThisWorkbook` refers to the workbook calling the macro.  When you run this, try having **only that one workbook open** and see if you still get errors.